# Notification button to stop or kill the player

Tags: android, android-notifications

On my radio streaming app i want to stop the player from playing.

**How to add a button in the notification to stop or kill the player?**

I have this so far:

```
private void initNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(StreamService.this, 0, new Intent(this, Radio.class), 0);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ricky)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon))
            .setContentTitle("Radio")
    builder.setContentIntent(intent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a close button to the notification layout. Create some intent like this:

```
final ComponentName srvComp = new ComponentName(getContext(), service.getClass());
Intent close = new Intent(YourRadioService.ACTION_PLAYER_CLOSE);
close.setComponent(srvComp);
mPiClose = PendingIntent.getService(getContext(), 4, close, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Inflate your RemoteView somehow, for example:

```
RemoteViews smallNotification = new RemoteViews(getContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
smallNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, mPiClose);
```

Set the content view on the notification

```
notification.contentView = smallNotification;
```

After that, use the notification manager to provide the notification

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Don't forget to handle the Intent. If you need more help look up how some open source music players are doing it.